# Timeseries charts with Bokeh

Tags: pandas, bokeh

Hi I am trying to create a timeseries chart using Bokeh.
The data I have looks like this, 2 columns one for the timestamp which is effectively the current time, the value and the sensor that provided the value

Time           |             Value     |     Sensor

2011-05-03 17:45:35.177000 | 213.130005|      A

2011-05-03 17:45:36.177000 | 208.83 |         B

2011-05-03 17:45:36.277000 | 212.629993 |     C

2011-05-03 17:45:45.317000 | 211.719999|      A

2011-05-03 17:45:45.577000 | 203.549999|      B

2011-05-03 17:45:48.177000 | 201.199999|      B

2011-05-03 17:45:55.175000 | 199.439999|      C

I am completely new to Bokeh
and I'm not sure how I can user bokeh to render the data for each of the sensors independently on a chart, something along the lines of [this](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/charts.html#timeseries)

- Do I need pandas as shown in the example?
- How can I use pandas to parse the timestamp column, from the example I can only see  pandas.parse_dates

Answer (score 1):

1) You don't *have* to use pandas, but this route makes it much easier.

2) You can parse the *time* feature by just using pandas' `to_datetime()` function ([pandas docs reference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html))

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter
import pandas as pd
import csv

d = pd.read_csv("SO.txt", delimiter="|")
# Strip whitespace from spacing in column headers
d.columns = [val.strip() for val in d.columns.values] 
d["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(d["Time"], yearfirst=True)

unique_sensors = d["Sensor"].unique()
c = ["red","blue","green"]

fig = figure(x_axis_label="Time (Seconds)", y_axis_label="Value", title="Sample")

# Draw a line for each unique sensor value
for i, s in enumerate(unique_sensors):
    sdf = d.loc[d["Sensor"]==s]
    fig.line(x=sdf["Time"], y=sdf["Value"], legend=s, line_color=c[i], line_width=3.0)
fig.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(hours=["%b %d %Y"],
                                            days=["%b %d %Y"],
                                            months=["%b %d %Y"],
                                            years=["%b %d %Y"])
show(fig)
```

But obviously you will need your color map to scale to your problem so I would suggest looking at bokeh palettes ([bokeh docs reference](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/palettes.html))